# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'undefined' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

[image]In a new reactjs project I have this basic code:

```
type User = {
  name: ?string,
  age: ?string,
};
const getUserName = ({name,age,}: User): ?string => name;
```

giving me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
```

What does this mean?

Am I not defining both User and its name just above?! Why is it saying I'm not?

Intention is:

```
const someUser = { name: "John", age: "12" }
const userName = getUserName(someUser)
console.log(userName)// should output 'John'
```

Comment: You need to pass an object of shape {name, age} in `getUserName` currently you are not passing any params

Comment: thank you, just fyi I'm a backend engineer so all this react kung-fu is new to me :), i thought i was passing an arg here '({name,age,}: User)' what's that then?

Comment: @jakstack you're declaring a function, the stuff between the `()` is the arguments for your arrow function. Here you're [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the arguments of an input object, which has the type of `User`.

Comment: Here you are defining the parameters the function accepts in your case it is an `object` of the shape `{name, age}` and you are destructuring that object. You want to use this function as `getUserName({ name: "John", age: 12 })`

Comment: thank you both Yash and Nick you are both correct so where is the problem then? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: the next step in my mind is to create a user object and call getUserNam(user), right? like this: const someUser = { name: "John", age: 12 }
const getUserName = getUserName(someUser)
console.log(userName)// should output 'John'

Comment: like this: const someUser = { name: "John", age: 12 }
const getUserName = getUserName(someUser)
console.log(userName)// should output 'John'

Comment: @jakstack The issue seems to be that you were calling `getUserName()` without passing anything into it. However, your second code block looks like it should work. I'm not that familiar with typescript, but are you sure `?datatype` is valid syntax? Running it in a playground seems to [complain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gWAFBSgOwEMBbCALigH45hEBLfAcwBoc9DHyqHhXsBfANw4AxgHt8NKJ2DwkAORLQ0ACnRFSzDhGb8KcxAEoK1Wg0aoAfASWCgA) when using `?` in front of the tags

Comment: thanks @NickParsons this code is a modified version of an existing app in live, tbh I'm not exactly sure what the ? means I'm assuming like in kotlin 'name: String?' means can be null or undefined

Comment: @NickParsons re "issue seems to be that you were calling getUserName() without passing anything into it." where?

Comment: Is this TypeScript, or Flow? Are you getting a runtime error or a compile time type error?

Comment: @jakstack The issue of "TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'undefined' as it is undefined." would occur when you pass nothing into your `getUserName()` function. [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=45#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gWAFBSgOwEMBbCALijmEQEt8BzAGhz0PvIIFdiAjJZ7AF8A3DgDGAe3xUo7YPCQA5EtDQAKdARVRBFBYgCUFKrQaoAfFtKjs4qTLgTS+1BiscARACkJAC3wejFBsHACMAEw6dtLAUJwIiMqkrnL6SRBqjs4JBtGOADYQAHT5EvRq8UoqBgD0NZS+Epz5ACZQTcBgnLEA5D7+PUA) is a working version of your code (with the types changed) - if you're using typescript that is

Comment: @Bergi Typescript vs Flow is a good question! not sure, I'm a backend guy all these years in development isn't helping me here, I feel like i know nothing :) lol

Comment: @Bergi runtime error in browser

Comment: Its neither flow or typescript. int data type is not what I'm aware of in either!

Comment: @NickParsons I used your code and attached the same error to question above, i think someone removed your code from comments, may be breaking rules ;)

Comment: @KarthikR 'int' isn't from live code it's my assumption could be wrong, sounds like wrong from what you said ;) will remove

Comment: @Bergi package.json looks like it's Flow

Comment: @jakstack If it's a runtime error, that means your calling `getUserName(undefined)` instead of `getUserName(someUser)` somewhere. Take a look at the stack trace to find which call it was, then track down why the value was `undefined` (despite using a type system that should help to prevent this kind of mistakes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add flow:

`npm install --save flow-bin`

or

`yarn add flow-bin`.

Comment: Please add why this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the good help!
It turned out to be missing flow once added [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-flow/) it all worked fine

finale version of the working code is:

```
type User = {
  name: ?string,
  age: ?string,
};
const getUserName = ({name,age,}: User): ?string => name;

const someUser = { name: "John", age: "12" }
const userName = getUserName(someUser)
console.log(userName)// should output 'John'
```